# UTF-8 Charset displaying french characters incorrectly.

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I am doing the folloiwing steps to import data into my e-commerce shop:

1. convert excel sheet to csv in excel
2. open csv file in notepad++ and convert to UTF-8
3. import csv file in phpmyadmin

If I look at the front end of the webpage the french characters are displayed as ?. The charset of the page is utf-8

If I change the charset to iso-8859-1 everything displays correctly.

If I check the item in the phpmyadmin the accents are displayed correctly.

How come utf-8 is not displaying them correctly? I thought it should display é etc.

If i go to the back end of the website and edit the product, the french description displays properly in the WYSIWYG editor. If I save then the product the french characters then show correctly. But this is because the WYSIWYG editor is converting the characters to html entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common issue when collecting Unicode DATA is leaving the Connection *and* database/table/column  character set configurad as ISO-8859-1, but then inserting data that is actually utf-8.  The database is essentially told, "here's some 8859-1-encoded data, store it in this 8859-1 table".  It doesn't  do any conversions because it doesn't realize the data isn't in 8859-1.  So the data is utf-8 but the database has essentially been told it's in 8859-1.

It's an insidious problem because, as you say, the database will convert them *wrongly* if you change your charset to UtF-8, since it will convert the "8859-1" data (remmember the databae *thinks* it's 8859-1) to utf-8 - a conversion that fails of course, as the data really is in utf-8.

So basically the problem is that phpmyadmin is in 8859-1 but you told it to insert the data in 8859-1 and then told it you were *providing* data in 8859-1, and then gave it utf-8 data.  The database thinks it's 8859-1 so the only easy way to solve the problem is to a) keep acting like it's 8859-1 even though it's not, and hope you never have to deal with sorting, searching, collation, etc ( may work in your case), or b) pulling out the data as 8859-1 ( leaving it unconverted ), then re-inserting it after setting the database and connection to utf-8 so the database knows what character set the data *really* is in.

Hope that makes sense.  Let me know if it doesn't.  This is a hard one to wrap your head around.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean after reading it a couple times. How can I see what charset the database is set to? I assume it is 8859-1 but when I go to the operations tab on the database it shows utf8_general_ci

Comment: Not sure about phpmyadmin but  in general https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html may help.  Basically, a server has a default charset, a table has one, a column might have a charset, and a connection has one too.  So an understanding of the big picture may be necessary.   If you examine the database in phpmyadmin you'll see the settings phpmyadmin has, not your application - they may not agree.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE xxx` is one way to see the character set on table xxx and its columns.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html shows server/conn variables.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider opening your csv with PHP (since you mention it in your tags), and use utf8_encode on the fields before saving them with queries.

Answer (score 0):

This question is so old, but changing the encoding of the file from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in various programs such as Excel etc was not working for me.

My issue is words like `intérêt` shows up as `intÃ©rÃªt` in the file.

In case this helps someone, here is what finally worked for me:

1. Starting with a CSV file, open in Notepad
2. Click "File > Save As".
3. In the dialog window that appears - select "ANSI" from the "Encoding" field. Then click "Save".

That's it! Opening this new CSV file using Excel should now show the non-English characters properly.